# strange mod_rewrite issue on one server but not another

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written some mod_rewrites that work fine on one server, but not another

mod_rewrite is working in general, for example going to http://site/about brings me to about.php on Server A and on Server B

But something strange is happening on Server B when the mod_rewrite goes another level forward

For example, on Server A, when I visit http://site/submit/bulk it brings me to submit_bulk.php, but when I visit that same location on Server B it brings me to submit.php.  It's like on the second server it picks the first mod_rewrite match (/submit) and doesn't keep looking for the actual match (/submit/bulk).

The same problems happen with the rss bits at the bottom, rss/submissions/nick works correctly on Server A, but on Server B its obviously just going to rss.php with no params passed

Can you see what might be wrong?

Thank you

```
IndexIgnore *
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^all-time/?$ "index.php?mode=all-time"
RewriteRule ^all-time/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=all-time&cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^all-time/cat/([^/\.]+)/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=all-time&cat=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^all-time/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=all-time&p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^cat/([^/\.]+)/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?cat=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^comment/?$ "comment.php"
RewriteRule ^comments/?$ "comment_list.php"
RewriteRule ^delete/c/([^/\.]+)/?$ delete_comment.php?comment=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^delete/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ delete_post.php?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^delete/u/([^/\.]+)/?$ delete_user.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ submit.php?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/u/([^/\.]+)/?$ edit_user.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^forgot/?$ "forgot.php"
RewriteRule ^login/?$ "login.php"
RewriteRule ^new/?$ "index.php?mode=new"
RewriteRule ^new/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=new&p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=new&cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^new/cat/([^/\.]+)/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=new&cat=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^register/?$ "register.php"
RewriteRule ^reset/about/?$ "reset_about.php"
RewriteRule ^reset/email/?$ "reset_email.php"
RewriteRule ^reset/forgot?$ "reset_forgot.php"
RewriteRule ^reset/pw/?$ "reset_pw.php"
RewriteRule ^search/?$ "search.php"
RewriteRule ^submit/?$ "submit.php"
RewriteRule ^submit/bulk/?$ "submit_bulk.php"
RewriteRule ^submissions/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=submit&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^submissions/([^/\.]+)/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=submit&user=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^submissions/([^/\.]+)/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=submit&user=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^submissions/([^/\.]+)/cat/([^/\.]+)/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=submit&user=$1&cat=$2&p=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/\.]+)/?$ profile.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/\.]+)/comments/?$ comment_list.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([^/\.]+)/comments/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ comment_list.php?user=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^ulist/?$ "user_list.php"
RewriteRule ^v/([^/\.]+)/?$ view.php?post=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^voted/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=vote&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^voted/([^/\.]+)/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=vote&user=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^voted/([^/\.]+)/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=vote&user=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^voted/([^/\.]+)/cat/([^/\.]+)/p/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?mode=vote&user=$1&cat=$2&p=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^rss/?$ "rss.php"
RewriteRule ^rss/all-time/?$ "rss.php?mode=all-time"
RewriteRule ^rss/all-time/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ rss.php?mode=all-time&cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ rss.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/new/?$ "rss.php?mode=new"
RewriteRule ^rss/new/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ rss.php?mode=new&cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/submissions/([^/\.]+)/?$ rss.php?mode=submit&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/submissions/([^/\.]+)/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ rss.php?mode=submit&user=$1&cat=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/voted/([^/\.]+)/?$ rss.php?mode=vote&user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^rss/voted/([^/\.]+)/cat/([^/\.]+)/?$ rss.php?mode=vote&user=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my 000-default file I notice:

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
allow from all

Removing MultiViews seems to fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you want to move the more specific conditions higher on the list so as to minimize the number of redirects?  i.e. put the /server/bulk condition first so it won't even hit the /submit condition.

Otherwise, there's a mod_rewrite option to check in either httpd.conf or in .htaccess called MaxRedirects, which prevents redirects from going into infinite loops. I believe MaxRedirects is set to 10 by default, but could possibly be set to 1 on the server that's being weird.  You may be able to override it in .htaccess by setting `RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10`.

Comment: That's probably more efficient, but changing the order doesn't seem to make a difference - I move /submit/bulk over /submit, and going to /submit/bulk still brings me to submit.php instead of submit_bulk.php